# Using the ThinkVantage button in i3

Tags: thinkpad, i3-window-manager, button-remapping

I am wondering how I can map the ThinkVantage Button in i3wm?

Volume raise button for example is `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`. What is the code for the ThinkVantage button, or if there is non, how else can I map it to a command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xev.
Install, run and press the key. It should show you the key code for the pressed key output in a console window.

Comment: Thank you. For anyone interested the Key is `XF86Launch1`